# Installing Android with LG Skin on Aquaris B5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, phone

I am thinking about getting an Aquaris B5 Ubuntu Edition (despite the fact that I am not too tech savvy).

I was wondering, whether it was possible to install the Android LG Skin on my Aquaris, in case Ubuntu Touch doesn't work for me?

I currently have a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.5 in case that makes any difference.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not impossible, if you have the required time and determination to learn how.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Android LG but you can install Android 5.1 for Aquaris E5 from the BQ website:

> > With the launch of the new Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition, queries are coming in from many BQ users: Can I install the new operating system
> >     on my Aquaris E4.5 or E5? The good news is yes, you can, although the
> >     tactile button functionality will depend on which system we install on
> >     the device.
>
> If you want to install Ubuntu on an Aquaris E4.5 or E5 with Android,
>   the tactile buttons on the screen will cease to functionality.
>
> However, if you have the Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition and want to
>   switch to Android, you will need to bear in mind that although the
>   screen´s tactile buttons are hidden, they will continue to work in the
>   same way as on the Aquaris E4.5 or E5. The only change is that they
>   won´t light up when you switch on the device.
>
> Now we will look closely at the steps for carrying a hard reset of the
>   device on both Linux and Windows.
>
> NB: This procedure can only be carried out on the Aquaris E4.5 and E5
>   devices. It is not available for any other BQ device.
>
> Hard reset on Ubuntu
>
> NB: The tool is only available for the most widely used version of the
>   Linux distribution, 12.04. However, by carrying out some additional
>   steps, you can install it on the latest versions, 14. 04 and 14. 10.
>
> 1. Download the necessary files
>
> To download the files, go to the Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Editon or Aquaris
>   E5 Ubuntu Edition pages if you want to install Ubuntu or the device or
>   the Aquaris E4.5 Android or Aquaris E5 Android pages if you want to
>   install Android. Download the necessary files for carrying out the HR
>   from the relevant page. Press “Download” to launch the download of a
>   file named “SP_Flash_Tool_exe_linux_v5.1424.00.zip”, that contains the
>   drivers required for the computer to recognise the phone, as well as
>   the hard reset tools + ADB Drivers. You will also need to download the
>   firmware corresponding to your device. In this instance, download the
>   current version of the hard reset firmware for either the Aquaris E4.5
>   Ubuntu Edition or Aquaris E4.5 from the relevant page. NB: You will
>   need to use a program like Win-RAR or 7-Zip to decompress the folders.
>
> 2. Decompress the files needed to carry out the procedure
>
> Go to the folder containing the
>   “SP_Flash_Tool_exe_linux_v5.1424.00.zip” file that you have
>   downloaded. Double-click on this file, and a WinRAR dialogue box will
>   open enabling you to decompress the contents. Press the “Extract”
>   button on the menu bar at the top and it will ask you where you want
>   to extract the files to. An ideal location is somewhere that is easy
>   to find, such as your PC´s desktop. Press on “Accept” to start the
>   decompression process.
>   3. Execute the MTK Flash Tool.
>
> With the latest versions of Ubuntu (14.04 and 14.10), the
>   “modemmanager” package installed on the computer is not compatible
>   with the MTK Flash Tool, so you will need to uninstall it first. This
>   package is used to control the modem connection via USB. Any user
>   configuration file will be maintained after uninstalling and
>   installing the package. This means that we can reinstall the current
>   configuration if required after using the tool. The following steps
>   are only necessary with the latest versions of Ubuntu. º We uninstall
>   the package mentioned above using these commands:
>
> ♦sudo apt-get remove modemmanager
>
> Uninstall the package Uninstall the package ♦sudo service udev
>   restartYou will be asked to enter your login password. A few command
>   lines will appear asking if you want to continue. Type in Y (yes) and
>   continue the process until it finishes
>
> Restart the udev service with out restarting the computer Restart the
>   udev service with out restarting the computer ° This could cause the
>   “cdc_acm” kernel module to be removed. You can check this by executing
>   the following command.
>
> ♦lsmod | grep cdc_acm
>
> Check the kernel module Check the kernel module º If it returns an
>   empty list, you will need to reinstall this module:
>
> ♦sudo modprobe cdc_acm
>
> Installing the cdc_acm module Installing the cdc_acm module You will
>   be asked to enter your login password again.
>
> From here on, the following steps are universal for all Ubuntu
>   versions: º Open the Ubuntu terminal and go to the directory of the
>   folder containing the tool that we have just decompressed. If you have
>   decompressed the folder on the desktop, the command to be executed in
>   order to move to it will be as follows (bear in mind that the command
>   will vary depending on which version of the tool you are using):
>
> ♦cd Escritorio/SP_Flash_Tool_exe_linux_v5.1424.00/
>
> Change to the folder of the tool Change to the folder of the tool º
>   Once in the corresponding directory, we need to give the tool
>   permission with the following commands:
>
> ♦chmod +x flash_tool
>
> ♦chmod +x flash_tool*
>
> Application permissions Application permissions º Now you are ready to
>   execute it. Remember you must execute it as superuser with the “sudo”
>   command. You will be asked to enter your login password.
>
> ♦sudo ./flash_tool.sh
>
> Command to execute the tool Command to execute the tool
>   4. Preparing the MTK Tool Flash to carry out a hard reset
>
> Once the command is executed by device, the tool will be open. MTK
>   Flash Tool MTK Flash Tool Press on the “Scatter-loading” button and
>   you will see a dialogue box enabling you to select the firmware that
>   you want to install on the phone (Ubuntu Edition or Android). In this
>   case, go to the firmware folder that we decompressed earlier and
>   select the text file that it contains, which will have a name similar
>   to “MT6577_Android_scatter”, and then press “Open”. Selection window
>   for the text file Selection window for the text file NB: to hard reset
>   to Ubuntu, the file will have the same name.
>
> Select “Firmware Upgrade” from the pull-down menu and press the
>   Download button. NB: Make sure that you have selected “Firmware
>   Upgrade” correctly. Selecting another option from the pull-down menu
>   could cause an irreversible system failure on your device.
>
> 5. Carry out the hard reset
>
> Turn your phone off and connect it to your PC using the USB to
>   micro-USB cable. When you connect it, the process will start. Wait
>   until it has finished and a window with a green circle and the word OK
>   will appear. Process completed correctly Process completed correctly
>   Once this window has appeared, you can close it, disconnect your phone
>   and then start it up as normal. NB: If there are any problems with the
>   tool when starting the hard reset, simply try again, without closing
>   the application. Close the dialogue box, confirm that the “Firmware
>   Upgrade” option is selected and click on “Download”. If it fails the
>   first time, subsequent attempts will work correctly.
>
> Windows
>
> 1. Download the necessary files
>
> To download the files, go to the Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Editon page to if
>   you want to install Ubuntu or the device or the Aquaris E4.5 Android
>   page if you want to install Android. Download the necessary files for
>   carrying out the HR from the relevant page. Press on “Drivers and
>   utilities” Press “Download” to launch the download of a file named
>   “Drivers&Tools.rar”, that contains the drivers required for the
>   computer to recognise the phone, as well as the hard reset tools + ADB
>   Drivers. You will also need to download the firmware corresponding to
>   your device. In this instance, download the current version of the
>   hard reset firmware for either the Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition or
>   Aquaris E4.5 from the relevant page.
>
> NB: You will need to use a program like Win-RAR or 7-Zip to decompress
>   the folders.
>
> 2. Decompress the files needed to carry out the procedure
>
> Go to the folder containing the “Drivers&Tools.rar” file that you have
>   downloaded. Double-click on this file, and a WinRAR dialogue box will
>   open enabling you to decompress the contents. Press the “Extract”
>   button on the menu bar at the top and it will ask you where you want
>   to extract the files to. An ideal location is somewhere that is easy
>   to find, such as your PC´s desktop. Press on “Accept” to start the
>   decompression process. 3 folders will appear: º “Drivers ADB”:
>   containing the ADB drivers.
>
> º “Drivers Hard Reset”: containing the drivers for the hard reset
>   process.
>
> º “MTK Flash Tool”: containing the tool to carry out the procedure.
>
> File contents File contents
>   3. Relocate the files to the corresponding place
>
> Move the folders that you decompressed (“Hard Reset Drivers” and “MTK
>   Tool Flash”) to the root of your PC´s hard drive “C:/” Go to the
>   firmware file and repeat the steps, decompressing and moving the
>   firmware folder to the root of your PC´s hard drive. Folders in C
>   Folders in C:
>   4. Install the drivers
>
> Access the “Hard Reset Drivers” folder which we have placed in the
>   root of your PC´s hard drive, and execute the “Install” or
>   “Install.bat” file. Start the function in a DOS window
>   “C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe”. It will ask for your permission to
>   install immediately, it will warn you that the drivers are unsigned
>   and ask if you still want to install them. Accept all until the DOS
>   window tells you to press any key to continue. Installation of the
>   drivers Installation of the drivers Installation process completed
>   Installation process completed Make sure your phone is off and connect
>   it so that the computer recognises it. Leave it connected for a few
>   minutes, until it starts to the install the drivers.
>   5. Prepare the MTK Tool Flash to carry out the hard reset
>
> If your phone is still connected from the previous step, disconnect it
>   now. Go to the “MTK Tool Flash” folder that you placed in the root
>   directory and execute the tool (“Flash_tool” or “Flash_tool.exe”).
>   Press on the “Scatter-loading” button and you will see a dialogue box
>   enabling you to select the firmware that you want to install on the
>   phone (Ubuntu Edition or Android). In this case, go to the firmware
>   folder that we decompressed earlier and select the text file that it
>   contains, which will have a name similar to “MT6577_Android_scatter”,
>   and then press “Open”. NB: to hard reset to Ubuntu, the file will have
>   the same name.
>
> Select “Firmware Upgrade” from the pull-down menu and press the
>   Download button. Prepare your tool Prepare your tool NB: Make sure
>   that you have selected Firmware Upgrade correctly. Selecting another
>   option from the pull-down menu could cause an irreversible system
>   failure on your device.
>
> 6. Carry out the hard reset
>
> Turn your phone off and connect it to your PC using the USB to
>   micro-USB cable. When you connect it, the process will start. Wait
>   until it has finished and a window with a green circle and the word OK
>   will appear. Process completed correctly_win Process completed
>   correctly
>
> Once this window has appeared, you can close it, disconnect your phone
>   and then start it up as normal. If the hard reset process doesn´t
>   start by itself when you connect the phone , check the next
>   procedures. Attempt one step at a time, and if you don´t get it to
>   work with the first one, then move on the next until you manage to get
>   it to work: Check that the drivers have been correctly installed. To
>   do this, go to the Devices Administrator and check that the phone is
>   recognised when switched off and connected to the PC, (it does not
>   appear with a yellow triangle, indicating that the driver has not been
>   installed correctly). Change to different USB ports on your PC. If
>   using a desktop computer, try connecting it to the ports at the back.
>   Make sure that the phone has sufficient battery power, at least 30%.
>   When you connect the phone, do it with the phone switched on, then
>   switch it off so that the PC recognises it at that very moment.

Check this link as the source and pictures:

http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-articles/2015/09/17/ubuntu-android-installation-process-for-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-e5/#/vanilla/discussion/embed/?vanilla_discussion_id=0

Comment: This is the version with proprietary google software, though, isn't it?

Does the LG Skin use proprietary google software as well?

Comment: I don't know. Is it just a skin for some other OS?

Comment: **@Pentaquark:** If you're not too tech savvy, Rocco's answer is the easiest and best you're going to get. Having said that: **Rocco**,  Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: @Fabby: I am not too tech savvy, but eager to learn, so any additional information is very welcome.

Do you guys know if the LG version of Android uses proprietary software from Google? Because I would like to avoid any closed-source google software, if possible.

Comment: @Pentaquark: **that question is off-topic here** and might best be asked over at [android.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I can see your point. Changed my answer accordingly, although it seems not exactly what Pentaquark asked for.

Comment: just to update the report, the flash update tool for linux ( the SP_Flash_Tool_exe_linux_v5.1424.00.zip) is now at http://spflashtool.com/  ... it should work for tablets and phones using MediaTek chips